# hive sql, serde how to not quote my fields?

Tags: csv, hive, double-quotes, hive-serde

Since by default serde quotes fields by ", How can I not quote my fields using serde?

I tried:

```
row format serde "org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde"
with serdeproperties(
"separatorChar" = ",",
"quoteChar" = "")
```

But i'm getting

```
FAILED: SemanticException java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achieve this by specifying `\u0000` as the quote character. Since `quoteChar` expects a string, you should use this unicode version of `NULL`.

```
ROW FORMAT SERDE
    "org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde"
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
    "separatorChar" = ",",
    "quoteChar" = "\u0000")
```

This unicode NULL `\u0000` is what used by the `CSV writer` class as value for `NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER`: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/AverysimpleCSVwriterreleasedunderacommercialfriendlylicense.htm

Answer (score 0):

For some reason `"quoteChar" = "\u0000"` didn't work for me as suggested in [Nirmal's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39445107/2202107).

When saving to file without quotes around the fields, I use:

```
-- saving to file
INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY 'file:/home/sidazhou/temp' 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
SELECT *
FROM temp_table
;
```

PS. I know this isn't what's being asked, which concerns `ROW FORMAT SERDE` instead of `ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS`.